# How to remove custom post type archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type called "recipe" with the `has_archive` parameter set to true. Visiting mysite.com/recipe/ gives a basic archive list of all the recipes posted and a page title of "Recipes". So far so good.

Now I'm looking to disable that recipe archive page (but keep individual recipe links working). My first thought was to try setting `has_archive` to false, which sounds like it should do the trick. Nope. The only difference this makes is the page title which for some reason becomes the name of the site. The actual archive is still displayed.

What is the best way to actually remove that archive completely? Is there a parameter of `register_post_type` that will achieve this or is it impossible and a case of a custom page template with a redirect in it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you flush your rewrite rules after setting `'has_archive' => false`?

Comment: Good point @ChipBennett, I did not! Works as expected now, thanks :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `has_archive` parameter for [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) does exactly what you expect it to do. However, it modifies rewrite rules when set. So, if you change it to `false`, you'll need to **flush your rewrite rules** in order for the archive index display to be removed entirely.

Comment: Note: this just needs to be done once. An easy way to do this is, for instance, to visit Settings->Permalinks and re-save the current settings. This will flush rewrite rules.

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually disable archives; it only disables the pretty URL for accessing them (`mysite.com/recipe/` in this example).  The archive still exists and is reachable at `mysite.com/?post_type=recipe` as long as the post type is publicly queryable.

Comment: how do you flush rewrite rules ?

Comment: @djack109 - It's literally written 2 comments above yours...